# Which item is the most gold efficient at this moment for Support?

Tags: league-of-legends

Several months ago I remember that Aegis of the Legion was one of the most gold efficient items.

But right now, with all those changes in items, it is still the more efficient one?

Comment: Worth noting that Aegis of the Legion no longer grants gold

Comment: @Oak I don't believe Aegis ever granted gold.

Comment: @MageXy It did not, I was thinking about Philosophers stone, mb

Answer (score 3):

**As of patch 7.9 this is no longer necessarily true, the 3 items were slightly changed** *(May 2017)*

*(This will be updated during the 20-22 of May weekend)*

- Spellthief's Edge/Frostfang

  - Gives *2 gold per 10 seconds*, and additional *8/15 for spells & basic attacks (3 stacks) respectively. Each stack recharges in 10 seconds.* Note that *killing a minion disables this passive.*
- Ancient Coin/Nomad's Medallion

  - Gives *2 gold per 10 seconds*, and additional *4/6 per enemy minion that die near you (if you didn't kill it) respectively.* Additionally *heals for 5/10 health for activating the previous effect* respectively.
- Relic Shield/Targon's Brace

  - Gives *2 gold per 10 seconds*, *melee autoattacks execute minions below 200 - 285 (based on level) health. Killing a minion by any means heals you and the nearest allied champion for 15 health and grants them kill gold. (2/3 stacks respectively). Each stack recharges in 40/30 seconds respectively.*

---

On paper the **Relic line** gives you 45.5 + 2*20.5 (Cannon + 2 Melee Minions) = 86.5 gold every 90 seconds.

On paper the **Spellthief's line** gives you 15*3 = 45 every gold every 30 seconds (135 every 90 seconds)

On paper the **Talisman line** gives you 6*6 = 36 gold per wave (54 gold every 90 seconds)

---

The problem is that realistically you can't always proc the Relic Shield's passive (Because sometimes your ADC just won't let you), or because doing so results in you dying. Same is valid for Spellthief's Edge, where not being able to hit the enemy or disabling the passive can mess up your gold income. As for Ancient Coin, you must be near minions for it to work (it's the most reliable), but gives a bit less, but it's balanced around the others not being able to be procced all the time (or at least risk dying to do so).

---

In the end it really depends on what your Champion is good at, and what stats you need the most early game (AP/Mana Regen, Health/dual-heals, self-heals/Mana Regen). This is true because on average all 3 items give the same amount of gold, and as such they have the **same gold efficiency**. Although *ideally* Frostfang has the most gold potential.

Comment: That's not *quite* what gold efficiency is, though it's very closely related. [Gold efficiency](https://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_efficiency) is about how cost-effective the item's stats are compared to how much the item actually costs to purchase. Based purely on stats, the three starting support items are actually not gold-efficient... but because they earn you more gold as the game progresses, they become gold-efficient later on.

Comment: True, but if you factor in that (depending on how you use it) it ends up generating much more gold than it costs, those 3 are by far the most efficient (after all, the more the game goes on the more you get). But I may have just misunderstood the question, as those 3 items are the only 3 items in the game where only the **Botlane Support** buys, since nowadays most Supportive items like *Redemption* or the *"Locket"* are used by Supportive champions/tanks in other roles (Such as Ivern Jungle for example)

Comment: I feel like your answer would better fit in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questitefons/154801/which-of-the-3-support-items-can-earn-you-the-most-gold). As @MageXy mentioned there's a difference between **gold efficiency** and **gold income**. [**Wiki for gold efficiency**](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_efficiency)

Comment: @Jutschge The linked question was deleted :/ . But yes you're right , but the nagain, it's not really possible to measure efficiency without discussing **how** you get that gold. If it was just passive you could argue that there's a curve where the item isn't efficient and eventually due to the gold you generate it becomes efficient, but since it's highly dependent on how you use the item, I feel like it's necessary to at the very least include a bit of number crunching for maxing the gold input. However in the edit I'm making due to the changes I'll consider adding a literal gold efficiency..

Comment: ... portion in the awnser

Comment: Oops I screwed up the link I guess. The question is still active: [**Correct Link**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/154801/which-of-the-3-support-items-can-earn-you-the-most-gold)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you build some gold per 5 items such as philosopher's stone and heart of gold. You constantly buy wards and would get a Shurelya's and an Aegis. This is mainly all I build when playing a support and also to occasionally buy an Oracle's Elixir.

---

*Note that this answer is no longer relevant due to:*

- Oracle's Elixir was removed in patch 3.14
- Philosopher's Stone was reworked into Nomad's Medallion in patch 3.14
- Shurelya's Reverie was reworked into Talisman of Ascension in patch 3.14
- Heart of Gold was removed in patch 1.0.0.152

Answer (score -1):

basically what blastmage77 said. gp5, buy wards, get an oracles so you can kill their wards, and then shurelyas. as for aegis, that depends on how much tankiness you need for your team, if they are tanky enough without it and you have a bunch of ad, then go Zeke's fervor, as the attack speed and lifesteal is an incredible buff for your team to get. as well as randuins omen, basically anything that your gp5 can turn into is cost efficient and worth it for support.

Answer (score -1):

Kiralirk hit the nail right on the head. Always get gp5 at the start and buy wards early. Evaluate the game and your team later on when you have a few thousand gold. Another good thing to keep in mind is that Kindle Gem only costs 850 gold, gives cool down reduction, and builds into Zeke's Herald, Shurelya's Reverie, and Soul Shroud, all of which are great support items. I recommend getting a Kindle Gem early.